# Count zero's in specific columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data like the table below.

```
10  0   11  5   11  5   16  5   
0   0   9   5   11  5   11  5    
12  0   12  5   12  5   12  5    
11  0   11  5   11  5   11  5
```

And I would like to ask you to know the logic in excel to count "0" value in every row and in column 1,3,5,7 only.

So that the answer will be `1` {1;0; 0; 0}

Thanks for your help.

Comment: use `CountIf` function...

Comment: thanks for your answer @KazJaw, but if I use countif, 0 value in second coloumn will be accounted too. in this case I just wanna count 0 value in spesific column and in every raw.

Comment: so, do it for each row separately, exact of similar to Chris answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little shorter:

*Updated to pick up on the empty cells issue*

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(COLUMN(A1:H4),2))* (A1:H4=0)*(LEN(A1:H4)>0))
```

Comment: Even though it jumps over columns as it should, it counts empty cells, not the zero value cells. Still, beautiful formula.

Comment: @Gimmy good point! now updated

Answer (score 1):

```
=sum(countif(a1:a4,0),countif(c1:c4,0),countif(e1:e4,0),countif(g1:g4,0))
```

Obviously you may need to extend your ranges if the real data is more than 4 rows.

Comment: Looks at even rather than odd columns ......

Answer (score 1):

;To get the exact output that you wrote, use this:

```
=CONCATENATE("[", COUNTIF(A:A, 0), ";", COUNTIF(C:C,0), ";", COUNTIF(E:E,0), ";", COUNTIF(G:G,0), "]" )
```

It uses the entire column as range. You can change that if you need.