# Excel sumproduct with condition

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

I want to SUMPRODUCT to ranges but only if there is no 0.

tried `=SUMPRODUCT(--(CN12:CN16="<>0");I4:I8)` but the results gets 0,

i have to ranges: CN12:CN16 and I4:I8, and CN12:CN16 can sometimes contain zeros. then i do not want to take that into the calculations and multiply with the value in I4:I8.

Any suggestions

Comment: if you're summing the product then ignoring zero values is the same as multiplying them

Comment: An example would be good....

Comment: What you have is looking to see if the text in CN12:CN16 is LITERALLY "<>0" it IS NOT testing to see if the VALUE of the cells is not 0. to do that just use CN12:CN16<>0

Comment: @JosieP I don't think you understand that concept he is trying to accomplish, I THINK he wants to Sum the values in I4:I8 that are related to the values in CN12:CN16 WHEN CN12:CN16 does not = 0 but DOES NOT want to multiply the value in CN12:CN16 with the values in I4:I8.

Comment: @user2140261 that's why I said 'if you're summing the product'. if that's not the case then, as barry houdini said, there is no need for SP here at all.

Comment: @JosieP Again, assumptions, SP could be needed if he is using anything older then '07

Comment: @user2140261 again, *I* made no assumptions (however your entire argument is based on what you *think* the case to be). no matter, SUMIF is present before 2007

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula to get the `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(CN12:CN16, I4:I8)
```

This evaluates AS:

```
=CN12*I4 + CN13*I5 + CN14*I6 + CN15*I7 + CN16*I8
```

So if one of the values equals to 0 that specific product equals to 0, and the rest of the products add to the total.

Here you have a [REFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313300/count-zeros-in-specific-columns/17314059#17314059) to evaluate if any of the cells in your range equals with zero.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually want to use CN12:CN16 values in the calculation or are they simply a criteria range? In SUMPRODUCT you don't need the quotes so this might be what you need -

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(CN12:CN16=<>0);I4:I8)`

although SUMIF will get you the same thing more easily

`=SUMIF(CN12:CN16;"<>0";I4:I8)`

Answer (score 0):

So solved it like this: `=SUMPRODUCT(CN13:CN17;$I4:$I8)/SUMIF(CN13:CN17;"<>0";$I4:$I8)`

As some of you wrote SUMPRODUCT gets zero if there is a zero in a list and then i check that list again in the SUMIF when i divided with the I4:I8. Maybe I was a little unclear in my description of the problem.

Thanks for your help.